# AccessViolationException using DirectShow but not in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, directshow

I am using WPFMediaKit to render webcam streams in WPF however on my Desktop when running the application I get an AccessViolationException when trying to build the DirectShow graph.

This doesn't happen on any of my other computers and the video stream can be loaded in the designer. I made sure the designer process no longer had a handle on the webcam before running but still doesn't work.

It throws an AccessViolationException on the following line when adding the capture device to the DirectShow graph.

```
hr = graphBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview,
                                           MediaType.Video,
                                           m_captureDevice,
                                           null,
                                           m_renderer);
```

What might cause this error? Is there any reason why it would work in the designer but not when I run the application? Running inside VS or not doesn't seem to make a difference neither does running as administrator.

Comment: Maybe you have a buggy codec installed which is not installed on your other computers. For example so called "codec packs" are known for this kind of problems.

Comment: Having access violation, you are always interested to publish access violation call stack.

Comment: I have no codec packs installed and nothing that should effect DirectX. I went as far as settings up a clean install on a VM to make sure. I believe I have found the cause of the access violation being 64bit driver for the capture device (Logitech C270) on Windows 8. The reason it works in the designer is Visual Studio and Blend both run in 32bit. With the same device on another operating system it will work in 64bit however any machine running Windows 8 causes an AccessViolationException when running in 64bit.